WordPress LiteSpeed cache causes random string to appear on shop page
I have a WordPress site that uses PolyLang. On the shop front in the secondary language the string '01ceea0b01";' appears at the top, and '01ceea0b01","isRTL":"","isCustomize":""};' appears at the bottom of the page.
Having done a bit of Googling on the topic, it looks like a plug-in is broken or incompatible. Fine by me, I can work round it.
The catch is this - these errant strings only appear when the cache is switched on. Without, the page loads perfectly. It's been like this for nearly a week. Previously, when the page was a little simpler, it didn't happen at all.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Does the issue happen with the default cache plugin settings? If not, probably you need to exclude certain files from being optimized or simply disable the optimization features.
